# Facing issues Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop on my machine but after complete installation I got a pop up warning that few packages are missing and you need to install them manually.
When I reboot my machine the network manager is not working, what should I do to solve this? 
Also if I try to erase complete disk and will install again, will this solve the problem?

Comment: It should, but make sure your connected to the internet when you do and choose the option to install third party software when installing!

Comment: Without reinstallation, is there any way?

Comment: It will require downloading the required packages which still needs the internet so my advice is to reinstall since it's a fresh install!

Comment: I am trying for a fresh installation still in logs I saw somewhere it is showing reading existing packages,

Comment: Does that stop the install?

Comment: No, but the same logs I saw earlier as well

Comment: Complete the installation and you have issues then report.

Comment: Network manager is working after this but I got few error messages at the time of restart

Comment: And what are these errors?

Comment: Print_req_error : I/O error,...

Comment: SQUASHFS error : read_data failed to read block